# Probability to have defective items

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An engineer tests the quality of produced computers. Suppose that 5% of computers have
defects and defects occur independently of each other. Find the probability:

a) of exactly $3$ defective computers in a shipment of $20$ (event A);

b) that the engineer has to test at least $5$ computers in order to find $2$ defective ones (event B).

Cand somebody give me some ideas, please? I don't know what probabilistic model to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model this problem as a [Bernoulli trial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial). Since defects occur independent of each other, the probability that any chosen computer is defective is $\frac{5}{100}$.

**Part 1**
First, out of the $20$ computers, we choose any $3$ which can be defective with a probability $\frac{5}{100}$ each, and the rest of the $17$ computers are non-defective with a probability $\frac{95}{100}$ each.

Thus, the required probability is given by:

$$P = C(20,3)\left(\frac{5}{100}\right)^3\left(\frac{95}{100}\right)^{17}$$

*Here I have used $C(20,3)$ to represent $\binom{20}{3}$*

**Part 2** For this part, you need to find the probability that at least $5$ tries are required to detect $2$ faulty computers. It will be a tad complicated to calculate this probability directly, so calculate the cases in which the $2$ defects are detected in $4$ tries or less. This too is a Binomial distribution. I encourage you to calculate this part on your own.